# How To add file to <Assets> folder on WP8 or WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to add a file to the  folder,
after I added that file,
I tried to add that file to the Assets folder in the solution,
But failed, it shows an error box:

```
"The desired name for "D:\....." is invalid
```

No matter how I tried to change the name of the file,
Still I can't add it to the solution folder.

Do I need to add some stuff into the *.xaml first?
What's the proper process to add a file to the  that WP will pack it into the final app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the assets folder in Solution Explorer and select the Add.Existing Item... menu option. Find the file you want to add and it will be copied to the Assets folder in the Solution.

To make sure it is also packaged with the app select the item's properties in Solution Explorer and make sure the Build Action is "Content". This will be the default for typical content types (.png, .jpg, etc.) but you'll need to set it explicitly for other content types.

If you don't want to add the file visually then you can directly edit the project file or create a mapping file and package the file yourself with makeappx rather than building it with Visual Studio.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply,
The problem is, when I do 'add existing item', it shows error box.
".... is invalid"

Comment: What is the file path and name? Is it local or on a remote share? Does this happen for all files or just the one?

Comment: I know why now, because I want to add file to a share folder.
I can't delete or add files to that folder... :-P.
But how to add/delete file from a shared folder...